# how to find out if a c++/cli heap variable has <undefined value>

Tags: variables, undefined, c++-cli, heap-memory

I've not been using C++ for about 4 years and came back to it a month ago, and that was where I also have first heard about the CLI extension. I still have to get used to it, but this website helps a lot! Thank you!! Anyway, I couldn't find an answer to the following problem:

When I declare a variable

```
int iStack;
```

then it is declared but not defined, so it can have any value like

```
iStack = -858993460
```

depending on what the value at the stack position is, where the variable is created.

But when I declare a variable on the heap

```
int^ iHeap
```

then as far as I know the handle is created but the variable is not instantiated (don't know if you call it instantiation here) or defined and I can only see

```
iHeap = <Nicht definierter Wert>   (which means <undefined value>)
```

**Is there any way to detect if this value is defined?**

I particularly don't need it for int, but for example for

```
array<array<c_LocationRef^,2>^>^ arrTest2D_1D = gcnew array<array<c_LocationRef^,2>^>(2);
```

to find out if the elements of the outer or inner array are instantiated (I'm sure here it is an instantiation ;-) )

```
arrTest2D_1D = {Length=2}
   [0] = {Length=20}
   [1] = <Nicht definierter Wert>  (=<undefined value>)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the CLR automatically initialise your variables and references in C++ CLI.

> In .NET, the Common Language Runtime (CLR) expressly initializes all
>   variables as soon as they are created. Value types are initialized to
>   0 and reference types are initialized to null.

To detect if your variable is initialised, you should compare the value of your hat variable to nullptr :

```
int^ iHeap;
if(iHeap == nullptr){
    Console::WriteLine(L"iHeap not initialised");
}
```

This works on my VS2010 ; it outputs `iHeap not initialised`
It should work for your specific problem as well (arrays).

By the way, value types are initialised to zero hence your first example should output 0 (I've tested it, and it does output 0) :

```
int iStack;
Console::WriteLine(L"iStrack = {0}", iStack); // outputs 0
```

Quote is from [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10439/Gain-performance-by-not-initializing-variables)
MSDN page for [nullptr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ex65770.aspx)

**EDIT:** Here is an other quote, from Microsoft this time :

> When you declare a handle it is automatically initialized with null, so it will not refer to anything.

Quote from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh184280%28v=vs.88%29.aspx) see the paragraph "Tracking Handles"

Comment: I don't know if CLI handles variables (or value types) different than C++, but afaik a declaration `int iStack;`
will not initialize the variable with zero, 
see also [wikipedia: Uninitialized variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninitialized_variable).
And as CLI has something like `value class`, I doubt that `int iStack;` defines a CLI value type, but I might be wrong.
But thank you for the hint at nullptr, that works!

Comment: Here's another explanation about it:  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7786921/why-we-must-initialize-a-variable-before-using-it

Comment: Yes, the CLR (virtual machine) does act differently than C++. In particular the variables are initialised. Anyway if your problem is solved you can close your post :p