# Not sure why C prints out NaN

Tags: c, math, calculator, integral, calculus

I was coding up a short program to compute right endpoints for a given graph (not shown here), so to avoid tedious computation, I decided to write up a short program to do the work for me. Yet my C program just prints out nan. I am very rusty on C, but I am not sure why I am getting NaN.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int x;
    float y, z;
    for (x = 0; x <= 8; x++) {
        y += 10.0 - (12.0 + (float)x) / 4.0;
        printf("%f\n", y);
    }
    z = 0.5 * y;
    printf("%f\n", z);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You never initialize `y` to anything.

Comment: Try with `float y = 0;`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049777/why-global-variables-are-always-initialized-to-0-but-not-local-variables http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212921/is-un-initialized-integer-always-default-to-0-in-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7786921/why-we-must-initialize-a-variable-before-using-it

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc None of those links got anything to do with the question...

Comment: @Lundin I'm not answering the question. I just show why the value wasn't initialized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 y = 10.0 - (12.0 + (float)x) / 4.0;
```

Followed by

```
y = y+1;
```

This makes sense else you have `y` uninitialized which leads to undefined behavior because the value of `y` is undeterminate.
During declaration you can initialize `y` and use `+=` operator.

Like

```
float y = 0;
```

Comment: Did I not initialize by using float y? Would I need float y = 0.0?

Comment: @Flair Yes `float y;` is just declaration you need to have a initialization like `y =0;`

Comment: In C, you have to specifically give the variable an initial value before start using it. In other languages, some will automatically initialize to 0.0 and some will issue compiler error.