# The valgrind reports error when printing allocated strings

Tags: c, printf, valgrind

The code is here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char* buf = malloc(3);
    strcpy(buf, "hi");
    printf("%s\n", buf);
    free(buf);
}
```

It's compiled with:

```
gcc a.c && valgrind ./a.out
```

The error message is here:

```
==1421== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==1421== Copyright (C) 2002-2010, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==1421== Using Valgrind-3.6.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==1421== Command: ./a.out
==1421== 
==1421== Invalid read of size 8
==1421==    at 0x4EA96C1: ??? (in /lib/libc-2.14.1.so)
==1421==    by 0x4E92D3B: puts (in /lib/libc-2.14.1.so)
==1421==    by 0x4005BB: main (in /home/peter/a.out)
==1421==  Address 0x51b4040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 3 alloc'd
==1421==    at 0x4C2740D: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1421==    by 0x400595: main (in /home/peter/a.out)
==1421== 
hi
==1421== 
==1421== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1421==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1421==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 3 bytes allocated
==1421== 
==1421== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==1421== 
==1421== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==1421== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 6)
```

It is also very strange that valgrind reports no more errors if I use the following (just one more space):

```
printf("%s \n", buf);
```

Would anyone please help me?

Comment: [You should **never** cast the result of `malloc` in C](http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html)

Comment: But I am using the g++ compiler and without the cast the error would be something like 'cannot convert from void* to char*'.  I have some other reasons for why I am not using 'new' instead of 'malloc'.

Comment: Your Valgrind output doesn't match the code you've posted. It shows `main()` calling `puts()`, but your posted code uses `printf()`. I don't think the compiler does that optimization automatically. Of course, you didn't specify if you built the program with optimization enabled.

Comment: You shouldn't build C code as C++, and then ask questions about it as if it were C. There are differences between C and C++.

Comment: @unwind I was skeptical at first but I actually ran the code (compiled with `gcc`) and it does produce a warning, but only when using `\n` after `%s`. "Address 0x41b3028 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 3 alloc'd".

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I am sure the output is exactly for this run.  Isn't it that c++ could still use c libs?  I did not enable optimization.

Comment: @cnicutar That's true.  If there's a space between %s and \n, the problem disappears.

Comment: @unwind I've tried another time with gcc instead of g++, removing the cast, but the problem remains still.

Comment: I think you're getting bitten by `puts` (where gcc replaced a trivial `printf`) using an optimized `strlen`, which in this case is doing 8 byte reads, thus reading past the end of your allocated region. You may want to report this as a bug

Comment: @Hasturkun In my case `valgrind` reported a 4-byte invalid read. Do you really think this is a bug ?

Comment: @cnicutar: there were similar issues with `strlen` in the past (eg. http://stackoverflow.com/q/3246008/20270 ), it's possible that updating valgrind will resolve this. It's a false positive in any case, AFAICT.

Comment: @Hasturkun: I'm already using the latest release of valgrind.  I change the allocated memory to 8 (or 16) bytes but more errors like 'Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)' occurred, and I don't know why.  I believe it's something I should report as a bug.  Thanks!

Comment: +1 to peter for providing a complete, compilable example in this question so that others can see everything that is going on and attempt to reproduce the problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug, but not reproducible on all machines.

On some machines, gcc optimizes simple `printf()` with, for example, `puts()`, which could possibly involve invalid read (or just valgrind thinks so).

If it really matters, you can 'complicate' the `printf` format.  A space between `%s` and `\n` would do.

Here is a similar bug: [C strings, strlen and Valgrind](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3246008/20270)

This answer combines comments in the discussion. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

I've run it in my own machine, and I get no errors:

```
==61755== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==61755== Copyright (C) 2002-2009, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==61755== Using Valgrind-3.5.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==61755== Command: ./a.out
==61755==
hi
==61755==
==61755== HEAP SUMMARY:
==61755==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==61755==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 3 bytes allocated
==61755==
==61755== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==61755==
==61755== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==61755== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 6)
```

Comment: So there's something wrong with my library or compiler?  I'am using the gcc-multilib for x86_64, if it matters.